# How i can resolve this issue with fonts and types

Tags: fonts

> So, i've been having problems for the load fonts, some text (not all) is goes with symbols
> appear the fonts

[symbols as fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsGig.png)

Comment: Did you check the picture you posted? I cannot make a lot of it. There is only a tiny square with some "d" letters. Not sure what problem that would illustrate.

Comment: some site replace text by this symbols.

Comment: I don't see a symbol on your figure, but if this is clear to other readers, then all is fine.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: stable, maintaining. how i can install fonts, arial, helvetica etc. ?